# EditTextView contents duplicated when used as an expandablelistview child

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an ExpandableListView that is using a couple of EditTextViews as children as follows :

[image]

The issue is when i enter something in one of the EditText fields and close the group the contents gets duplicated in a separated group or sometimes in both of them.

My adapter just returns a fixed number of child views, here is the code :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Inflate layout and return rowView

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Inlfate layout and return rowView
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have tried using a ViewHolder and i get the same result. What do i need to do to prevent the contents being duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the issue with the `ExpandableListView` is that the getChildView is called each time you expand a child view. This causes the views to be re-used.

To solve this i disabled view recycling by inflating the child view layout and creating a HashMap to store the value of the `EditText`

```
private  String title;

private  HashMap<String, String> holder = new HashMap<>();

public MyAdapter(String title){
    this.title = title;
}
```

And then in the getChildView method i do the following :

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_child, parent, false);

    final EditText etFirstName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_first_name);
    final String value =  holder.get(String.valueOf(groupPosition + childPosition));

    etFirstName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            holder.put(String.valueOf(groupPosition + childPosition), s.toString());
        }
    });

    if (value != null){
        etFirstName.setText(value);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

To enable doing the same thing for multiple views, you can create a model object and use the `groupPosition + childPosition` as the key for the `HashMap`.